# Javascript new feature?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if its new feature or just a working bug

Before I used to do like

HTML :

```
<div id="identity">I am an demo text</div>
```

JS :

```
let iddiv = document.getElementById("identity");
console.log(iddiv)
```

but Now I can do

```
console.log(identity)
```

Withour storing the element in a variable

I just wanted to ask if it is fine !!

```js
console.log(identity)
```

```html
<div id="identity">I am an demo text</div>
```

Comment: Do not rely on elements with an  id being available as global variables. It may clash with other variables. Stick to using `document.getElementById()`

Comment: It is an _old_ feature and comes with many pitfalls and problems, so you should rather not use it.

Comment: @CherryDT Yeah. In general, don't trust anything that crawled out of IE.

Comment: @VLAZ - You mean like `querySelectorAll`? ;-) Until they came to an abrupt halt once IE6 came out, Microsoft were actually innovating in the browser space. Then, of course, they went very dark. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, *in general*. There are exceptions, of course but most of the time you should be on your guard.